# Suprema and Infima of nonpositive functions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to get some estimates using the time-dependent infimum and supremum of a function $g(t,x)$. I have the following question. Suppose $g(t,x)\leq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\geq0$. Further set

$$m(t)=\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}g(t,x)$$

and suppose $h(y)$ is a positive function satisfying $\int_0^{\infty}{h(x)dx}=1.$

The following estimate makes sense to me, but I would like a second opinion due to the time dependence:

$$
\int_0^{\infty}{h(y)g(t,x)^2dx}\leq\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|g(t,x)|^2\int_0^{\infty}{h(y)dx}
=\left(-m(t)\right)^2=m(t)^2,
$$
where the switch from $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|g(t,x)|^2$ to $(-m(t))^2$ is due to $g$ being nonpositive.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any flaws in your logic.

Comment: Greatly appreciated.